# Get script project source URL from published Web App URL

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks

I have web hook url like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec`, and need to find the project files associated with it.
I know that the associated file (Google Sheets) is owned by our company, but the scripts were made by my predecessor.

Accessing the URL returns an error:
`Script function not found: doGet`

I want to find and fix the script, or disable the web API.

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. In your situation, you are required to find a project, that Web Apps had been deployed before, from the projects without the function of `doGet()`. Is my understanding correct? 2. How much number of files will you find only one project from? 3. Do you know that what type of project the Web Apps deployed is? Container-bound script type or standalone script type? 4. If it's the bound script type, how much number of Google Docs files for searching are there?

Comment: @Tanaike

thanks for your comment.
1. yes, that's right.  
2. 106 files in my project.
3. i'm not sure. but i think it is Container-bound script(Google Spread Sheet).
4. i think it's same as the number of Question2. so i mean 106 files.

Comment: @sinaraheneba
thanks for your edit suggestion!

Comment: @Tanaike
I read your comments and found a solution.
I only have 106 files. so i checked them one by one.
it may not be a clever way, but i solve my problem.

thanks for your comment. thank you!

Comment: In case you need to do something like this again - instead of checking all files one by one manually, you can do it programmatically with a script which lists all your scripts, retrieves their web deployment Ids and compares them against the Id you are looking for. A link to an already existing answer implementing this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989056

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find apps script published URL from file URL - search files by published Web App URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986609/find-apps-script-published-url-from-file-url-search-files-by-published-web-app)