# Insufficient permissions to troubleshoot policies in IAM+ enable API for Google Apps Script Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm currently trying to implement a solution from this answer here: [Find apps script published URL from file URL - search files by published Web App URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986609/find-apps-script-published-url-from-file-url-search-files-by-published-web-app/50989056#50989056)

Unfortunately, I'm unable to follow this specific step here:

> When you run the code for the first time, you'll get a prompt to
> authorize the permissions. But even after you authorize the
> permissions, you'll still need to go to the developers console and
> enable the Apps Script API for the project.

This is due to the fact that when I do follow the prompt in the script logs to go to the URL and enabled the API for the project, I'm running into "insufficient permissions" to view the page, and "you do not have the required permissions to troubleshoot policies on the specified resource" upon troubleshooting.

[image: insufficient permissions]

I'm struggling to understand what this actually means, as we've not encountered this issue before. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Can you share more information on the step that is failing? When you execute the script from the script editor you get a review permissions. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. The prompt to review permissions for the API comes through the logger output of the script (as per the original thread I've linked). Issue lies within the screenshots.

Comment: I guess you have enabled the api, have you also checked the script Id is correct, all the permissions, etc?