# Getting the the dev url instead of exec url in a deployed app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a bound script attached to google spreadsheet as an add on, and I also have a `doPost()` inside the bound script to act as a webhook for requests from my back end. I have deployed my app to test if my `doPost()` function works, and it does. The problem I am facing is that if I run my script from the spread sheet in which my app script is attached, I am getting a dev url when I call `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` . When I use this dev Url, it is not calling my `doPost()` function, but instead returns with the following error:

```
Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check address and try again.
```

However, what I find interesting is that if I were to log the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` inside my `doPost()` and make a request to the exec url from postman, it returns the correct exec url. So now, I a can only assume that because I am running my code from the spreadsheet, it is treating it as a different web app? I say this because when I call `ScriptApp.getService().isEnabled()` outside of the `doPost()` (in a different function inside the same script), it returns true.  Is there a way to get the exec url when I run my app script from google spreadsheet? Do I have to do something else other than deploying from the app script editor?

Edit: To further clarify, I have not published my app script. Could this be the reason why?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986609/find-apps-script-published-url-from-file-url-search-files-by-published-web-app) will get you what you need?

Comment: @RemcoE33 Thanks for the suggestion, I will check it out.